# Is there a way to limit the scope of the targets from a find_package() command to a single function

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I have a cmake function to compile plugins by taking the plugin name and then all the dependencies required.

It looks like this

```
function(CreatePlugin PluginName)
    set(targets "${ARGN}")
    foreach(target IN LISTS targets)
        if( NOT TARGET ${target})
            message(STATUS "Skipped ${PluginName} plugin. Target ${target} not found." )
            return()
        endif()
    endforeach()

    add_library(${PluginName}Plugin SHARED ${PluginName}Plugin.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PluginName}Plugin ${targets})
    target_include_directories(${PluginName}Plugin PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/plugins)
    install(TARGETS ${PluginName}Plugin DESTINATION plugins)
endfunction()
```

and it gets called like this

```
CreatePlugin(myPlugin dep_1 dep_2 ... dep_n)
```

where dep_1 ... dep_n are targets.

my problem is that right now I am getting dep_1 .. dep_n by calling find_package() outside the function, which means those targets come into scope for the entire project.

Somewhat like this

```
find_package(some-lib)
CreatePlugin(myPlugin someLib)
```

I want to structure the CreatePlugin function in such a way where I can pass in the find_package() command as a parameter so those targets only exist in that scope.

Comment: "Normal" targets has global visibility. Visibility of IMPORTED targets and their ALIAS'es is limited to the current directory and subdirectories. You cannot define a target which visibility is restricted by a function's scope. Moreover, the mere intention to do that looks weird. What is wrong in global visibility of targets in your case?